# Saving SQLite query results as variables

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

So basically I'm looking to try to make a basic login for a WPF app and store certain user data into variables with C#. Problem I'm running into is separating the result of different datatypes into variables to use later in the app. Something similar to the GET command in PHP. I have seen some documentation about creating a separate class replicating the data you need and could probably run individual queries for each variable, but that just feels wrong and I know there's a better way.

Here is my code so far:

```
Database databaseObject = new Database();
var userid = LoginTextBox.Text;
string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = @userid";
SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, databaseObject.myConnection);
databaseObject.OpenConnection();
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
SQLiteDataReader result = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (result.HasRows)
{
/* GET RESULT INTO VARIABLES */
}
else
{
LoginTextBox.Text = "";
}
databaseObject.CloseConection();
```

Don't think I'm too off here just need a push in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `User` class that has all the properties coming back from the table.

Something like:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And then just read the properties from your `SQLiteDataReader` and assign them to the properties of the class:

```
var user = new User();
user.UserId = (int)result["userid"];
user.UserName = (string)result["username"];
```

Comment: Or better yet, use something like Dapper so that you don't need to assign all of those properties manually.

Comment: Absolute legend thanks mate o7 I was basically on this path but not quite there, will look into Dapper as well

Comment: Or even web-search an `ORM` comparison like "dapper vs entity framework core vs nhibernate"

Comment: @DarkApogee As others have said you can also explore the Dapper route, I was giving the basic option first before giving suggestions on ORMs, even the simple ones like Dapper.

Comment: @Patrick I went with your route anyway, it was too simple to feel as though I needed an ORM. The absolute legend mate was directed at you :)